# Dropdown function is losing words after space in submitted output

Tags: php, forms, function, select, post

I'm trying to create my first function in PHP, a drop down. It's almost working, but when I submit/post the data the options with a space in it will only show the first word in the output.

In the example I have 'First Name' as an option in the drop down list. When I hit submit, the output will only be 'First'. When I change 'First Name' to 'First-Name' it works, the output is 'First-Name'. So I think I need to add quotes somewhere in the code so that it is handled as a string??

Hope someone can help me out, I'm so close to what I want.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<?php

include('db_functions.php');

function clean_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
} 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   $fName = clean_input($_POST['first_name']);
}

//drop down function
function dropdown($name, $options) {
    $dropdown = '<select type="text" name='.$name.'>'."\n";
    $rows = $options;
    if($rows === false) {
        $error = db_error();
    }
    $totalrows = count($rows);
    for ($x = 0; $x < $totalrows; $x++) {
        $dropdown .= '<option value=' . $rows[$x][$name] . '>' . $rows[$x][$name] . '</option>'."\n";
    }
    $dropdown .='</select>'."\n";
    return $dropdown;
}



echo '<form action="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '" method="post">';

//start dropdown
echo 'First Name:';
$name = 'first_name';
$options = db_select("SELECT DISTINCT first_name FROM nametable GROUP BY first_name ORDER BY first_name ASC LIMIT 20");
echo dropdown($name, $options);

//end dropdown

echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">';
echo '</form>';

echo $fName;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add code of `clean_input` function?

Comment: Thanks. I added the clean_input function to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is writing

```
<option value=First Name>
```

The space ends the value, so `Name` is a separate attribute. You need to put the value in quotes, so it's

```
<option value="First Name">
```

The code should be:

```
    $dropdown .= '<option value="' . $rows[$x][$name] . '">' . $rows[$x][$name] . '</option>'."\n";
```

Comment: That was the problem. Now it seems so obvious! Many thanks!